# How is connected Envelop From and Mail From mail header?

Tags: email, dns, spoofing, dkim, spf

I was looking into mail header of a newsletter message sent by my company.
I cannot understand how an external server (newsletter provider) can send message with them as envelop from but with my domain as mail "from" without any DNS configuration given to newsletter provider.

I know that SPF and DKIM are related to envelop, but after the envelope passes SPF checks, can it send message with any mail from header?
Is nothing that link envelop to mail from?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By default there is no link at all. SPF protects against spoofing Envelope-From but not RFC822 "From:". DKIM signatures verify the RFC822 "From:" header but ignore Envelope-From (because it isn't part of the data but part of the transport)

A link is created only if the sending domain has a DMARC policy – once that's present, recipients supporting DMARC will require that the two fields be "aligned", that is, the RFC822 "From:" domain must either exactly match the Envelope-From or (in relaxed mode) at least be a subdomain of Envelope-From, and similarly it must either exactly match or be a subdomain of the DKIM signer domain.

(The downside of DMARC alignment checks is that messages can no longer be legitimately auto-forwarded from one mailbox to another, unless their "From:" header is rewritten. This has caused many problems for mailing lists in the past, as they cannot preserve the original sender anymore.)